# Hull White Stochastic Volatility Model in Matlab

Tags: stochastic-volatility, matlab, hullwhite

I'm trying to code the Hull White stochastic volatility model using matlab and somewhere my code seems to mess up. I've coded the SABR model as well and that's working fine. When I compare prices obtained between my two models, there seems to be a linear relationship (which is what I expect if I've done the Hull White correctly). 
[image: Hull White SABR price comparison]

When I produce implied volatility smiles for the Hull White, it looks something like this: 
[image]

I'm using the pricing formula for the Hull White model:

[image]

This is the procedure I'm following for my code:

1. Simulate Paths of sigma using the Milstein scheme for discretising an SDE
2. Average points at each time incriment for all the simulations and compute \bar{V}.
3. Find the Black Scholes Price
4. Compute Implied Volatility.

It's definitely going wrong somewhere so if anyone has the time to look through my code I'd be soo grateful! thanks in advance

```
function [Imp_Vol, Price] = Hull_White(S0, K, r, sigma0,gamma,alpha, T, M)


%   Monte Carlo European Call Option with Local Volatility using the Milstein Scheme. 
%   S0 - Underlying price at T=0
%   K - Strike Price
%   T - Time to Maturity in Years (please input uniform decimals ie 1.5,
%   2.9)
%   r - Interest rate
%   sigma0 - Volatility
%   gamma - Variable in Hull White model
%   alpha - Variable in Hull White model
%   M - Number of Monte Carlo Simulations 
%   Output price - corrosponding option price

N=floor(T*260); % Days to maturity

dt=1/260; % incriment for descretization

sigma_path = zeros(N,M);

for j=1:M % starting the Monte Carlo Simulations

    Z=randn(N,1);  % N random numbers to approximate dWi
    sigma=zeros(N,1); % initialising the volatility path vector

    sigma(1) = sigma0;

     for k=2:N % Calculating the volatility Path using the Milstein Scheme

            sigma(k) = sigma(k-1)*(1 + sqrt(dt)*gamma*Z(k-1) + dt*(alpha + 0.5*gamma*gamma*(Z(k-1)^2-1)));
     end
     sigma_path(:,j)=sigma;
end
sigma_integral = mean(sigma_path')';
sigma_integral_squared = sigma_integral.^2;
dt_vector = dt*ones(N,1);



V_bar = mean(sigma_integral_squared'*dt_vector); %numerical integration

[Call, Put] = blsprice(S0, K, r, T, V_bar, 0);
Imp_Vol = blsimpv(S0, K, r, T, Call, [],[], [], []);
Price = Call;
end
```

Comment: You're discretisation scheme seems weird to me. As you've defined it, the SDE for $\sigma_t$ is a simple GBM. So why would you bother with a Milstein scheme? Euler on log-returns should be fine (ie replace $\times (1+...) $ by $\exp (...) $ and get rid of the $z (k-1)^2$

Comment: Also you should (1) calculate the time integral $\hat {V}^{(j)} $ over each path $j=1,...,M$ then (2) apply the BS formula to get $C (\hat {V}^{(j)}) $ and finally (3) average all of these to get $P_0=\frac {1}{M} \sum_{j=1}^M C (\hat {V}^{(j)})$. Istead what you did is: average all the simulated paths to compute an average path integral and apply BS. Remember that the expectation of a function is not the function of the expectation of its argument.

Comment: @Quantuple Thank you so much! I completely forgot about Jenson's inequality.

Comment: @Quantuple We learnt that using the Milstein scheme produces a smaller discretisation error so I thought it'd be safer using that rather than Euler.

So you propose I use the line:

sigma(k) = sigma(k-1)*exp(sqrt(dt)*gamma*Z(k-1) + dt*(alpha + 0.5*gamma*gamma));

instead?

Comment: Your claim that Milstein scheme is better than Euler is in general true, but for the GBM case I think the difference is not significant, at least if you use Euler on log-returns. No, the equation you provide is wrong, in the last term of the exponential you should have "0.5*gamma*gamma" with a minus sign instead of a plus. Also, it's Jensen not Jenson :)

Comment: if the answer below helped you. Don't hesitate to mark it as accepted :) if not please explain why so someone can further help.

Comment: It looks like you are getting some good advice here. Hopefully, you resolved your issue. I am very curious to see your implementation of the SABR model. Would you be willing to share it?

Comment: @drobertson I've just coded the asymptotic solution that Hagan puts forward for now. I can share that with you if you want?

Comment: @drobertson I've also worked out the PDE which the price of an option should follow under the SABR model so I'm currently in the process of discretising that to hopefully implement it as another method. I can send you across the PDE as well if you'd like.

Comment: Yes, I would like to see your solutions. Especially the SABR models.

Comment: @drobertson  [Here's] (http://imgur.com/SJdXKPd) the PDE I have for the SABR model. 
All terms should be apparent from Hagan's description of the SABR model dynamics, and λ* is the market price of risk (left up to the user).

Comment: @drobertson Here's my SABR model code. Let me know if you have any questions

[imp_vol, Price] = SABR(f0, K, T,alpha,beta,rho,nu, r)
if (f0==K)
    imp_vol = (alpha)/(f0^(1-beta))*(1+T*( (1/24)*((1-beta)^2)*(alpha^2)*(1/(f0^(2-2*beta))) + 0.25*(rho*beta*nu*alpha)*( 1/(f0^(1-beta))) + (1/24)*(2-3*rho*rho)*nu*nu ));
    Price = blsprice(f0, K, r, T, imp_vol, 0);
else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to compute 
$$ P_0 = \mathbb {E}[C (\hat{V})] $$
where
$$ \hat{V} = \frac {1}{T} \int_0^T \sigma^2_s ds $$
and
$$ d\sigma_t = \sigma_t (\alpha dt + \gamma dW_t) $$
using Monte Carlo, you should:

1. Generate stochastic volatility paths over $[0,T]$ by discretising the above SDE (which here defines a GBM, not a Hull & White diffusion)
2. Calculate the time integral $\hat {V}^{(j)} $ for each simulated path $j=1,...,M$, you can use a trapezoidal integration method for instance.
3. Apply the BS formula to compute $C (\hat {V}^{(j)}) $
4. Average all of the latter call prices to finally obtain
   $$P_0=\frac {1}{M} \sum_{j=1}^M C (\hat {V}^{(j)})$$.

Instead what you did is (see bullet points in your original question): average all simulated stochastic volatility paths to derive an "average volatility path" from which you calculate an average volatility $\hat {V} $ over $[0,T] $ and apply BS formula using the latter volatility figure.

Your approach is thus wrong. Remember that the expectation of a function of a random variable is in general not the function of the expectation of that random variable (except for linear functions obviously), see Jensen's inequality.

It is a common rookie mistake though, don't worry :)

Comment: is trapezoidal discretization preferable over rectangular (starting at $\sigma_0$)? slightly wondering about the implications of using $\sigma_T$ given  the conditioning.